# How to handle multiple errors from different async pipes in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, pipe, interceptor

I have 2 `mat-select` that each one of them uses `async` pipe in my component:

```
    <div class="flex-col">
        <mat-label>Issue Desc
        </mat-label>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select [(value)]="model.issue_Desc" 
                [(ngModel)]="model.issue_Desc"
                name="issue_Desc" required>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let issues of (this.IssueObs$ | async)" 
                    [value]="issues.issueDesc">
                    {{issues.issueDesc}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col">
        <mat-label>Area Desc</mat-label>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select [(value)]="model.area_Desc" 
                        [(ngModel)]="model.area_Desc"
                name="area_Desc" required>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let area of (this.AreaObs$ | async )" 
                        [value]="area.areaDesc">
                    {{area.areaDesc}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Whenever the JWT token expires on my website it returns two `401 Unauthorized` errors upon loading the component, which causes trouble for me when sending the user back to the login screen with a "Session Ended" toaster message because I am getting a duplicate message of it when being handled in my interceptor.

Here is my interceptor code:

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): 
            Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            timeout(10000),
            catchError(error => {
                if (error) {
                    switch (error.status) {             
                        case 401: 
                            if (error.error == null) { 
                                //Goes here when token expires

                                this.toastr.info("Session has ended!")
                                //<<---- Gets executed twice
              
                                this.accountService.logout();
                            }
                            else {
                                this.toastr.error(error.error)
                            }

                            this.dialogRef.closeAll();
                            this.router.navigateByUrl('')

                            break;
                    }
                }
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }
```

[image: The 2 errors from different async pipes]

[image: The 2 Duplicate "Session ended" messages from different async pipes]

How do I handle these errors to only display one message when there is more than one error happened from `async` pipe?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: could it be that you are accidentally making two api calls and both of them are failing individually , can you check your network, also debug and check in code how many times the api calls is being made

Comment: my problem is that I am trying to get only 1 error instead of 2 when my token expires. I was thinking at first that if 1 async pipe fails the other would cancel , but that is not the case. @vaira

Comment: Use ‘throttleTime’ there u can put 3000 as limit, if multiple api fails in 3 second u will only get alert once

Comment: You can also use  distinctUntilChanged(), that will only pass error if reason has changed

Comment: do you mean use `throttleTime` like this? ` this.AreaObs$ = this.areaService.AllAreas().pipe(throttleTime(3000));` . It is not working with me

Comment: Not on service level use it on interceptor

Comment: like this? `  return next.handle(request).pipe(
      timeout(10000) , 
      throttleTime(3000), ... ` . Now no requests on my api work , please be more specfic if that is not what you meant. @vaira

Comment: Sorry was replying from mobile, added an answer

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting multiple request is becase intercept function it trigged multiple times, and pipe operators are working in parallel,

*request are not going through the same/shared pipe, so one `pipe()` is working per `request`*

You can create a subscription in Interceptor where you push error when they occur and then you can perform `throttleTime` or `distinctUntilChanged`

```
 @Injectable()
export class I1 implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor() {
  this.errorLog$ = new Subject();
  this.errorLog$
  .pipe(throttleTime(2000)) // all error will pass this pipe sequentially 
  .subscribe(e => console.log('log:', e));
}

  private errorLog$ : Subject<any>;
  
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> { // triggered with individual request
   
    return next.handle(req).pipe( // every request create their own separate pipe
      catchError((e) =>
       {
       this.errorLog$.next(e); // push error in a single observe
          throw e;
       }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I can see on console that it subscribed only once and output the subject using ` console.log(this.errorLog$)` two times.

Comment: what exactly is the issue, if api calls are failing in parallel, this should solve the problem, if those two calls are made few seconds apart (which should not be the case) this will fail.